# Sort by meta_value then by post date

Tags: wordpress

The query currently sorts posts by meta_value only, but I'd like to include the post date as a second variable to sort by.

I tried using this:

'orderby'  => 'meta_value post_date',

But the sorting did not change

```
//values
$posts_per_page = 15;

//define custom query parameters
$custom_query_args = array(     
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category_name'     => $category_slug,
    'posts_per_page'    => $posts_per_page,
    'meta_key'          => 'status',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be pretty simple...since the post date is already defined by wordpress you can put orderby values into an array.

```
//define custom query parameters
    $custom_query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => $category_slug,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'meta_key' => 'status',
        'orderby' => array(
            'meta_value' => 'DESC',
            'post_date' => 'ASC'
        )
    );
```